# React-native(IOS) App gets stuck on splash screen in debug mode throwing NSException

Tags: ios, react-native, release, remote-debugging, metro-bundler

Here are my findings:

**Release Mode**

```
Build got succeed in release mode running through the Xcode(11.4.1)
```

metro bundler is loaded but not getting indexing in it. App is working
fine without loading bundler. made some changes in code but those
changes are not reflecting, not getting console and alert messages.

- Tried to debug it through safari, in develop menu, getting inspect
  application in simulator, opened js context but not getting console.
- Web inspector setting missing in IOS simulator Safari. Installed
  safari technology preview and updated the OS, but didn't work. (I think no need to enable web inspector in simulator, by default it is enabled - As per my Googling)

This is the system configuration

- macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
- Xcode (11.4.1), react-native 0.59.5

**Debug Mode**

```
* Build got failed in debug mode, throwing exception.
178 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
see invocation)
```

Removed -ObjC from other linker tag in Target. after removing tag, build got succeed in debug mode too but app is getting crashed on splash screen terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

- Created one new project with 0.59.5  react-native and 11.4.1 Xcode . This is completely working fine, metro bundler got loaded, getting option for debugging by pressing cmd +D. able to build app through Xcode and command (react-native run-ios) too.
- Compared Xcode settings of both the projects. for saral app, test
  app is not appearing in Xcode (not sure  whether this is the reason
  behind it).
- We are not using pod (perhaps this is the reason), tried to add the pod in project but 0 dependencies added.
- Tried to Build with XcodeProject and workspace too with legacy build system but didn't work.
- Tried to run in multiple simulator with multiple Xcode versions.
- Duplicates libraries are not added.
- main.js file is there.
- we are not using firebase and image cropper.

```
   **Exception Log :** 
`2021-08-09 12:43:39.613 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:213] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7fc3d73064d0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x600002e00d90>, executor: (null))
2021-08-09 12:43:39.616978+0530 SaralAccountsMobile[11019:168611] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7fc3d73064d0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x600002e00d90>, executor: (null))
2021-08-09 12:43:39.909175+0530 SaralAccountsMobile[11019:168611] -[RCTRootView reactTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3d7405d10
2021-08-09 12:43:39.967846+0530 SaralAccountsMobile[11019:168611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTRootView reactTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3d7405d10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff7cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f93e9b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff9dc34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000118073058 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 302
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff816b6 ___forwarding___ + 838
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff83bf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d6b246f -[RCTRootView reactTag] + 271
    7   SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d6b29b6 -[RCTRootView bundleFinishedLoading:] + 438
    8   SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d6b14d1 -[RCTRootView initWithBridge:moduleName:initialProperties:] + 2049
    9   SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d6b16cd -[RCTRootView initWithBundleURL:moduleName:initialProperties:launchOptions:] + 221
    10  SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d65fd14 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 244
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011803ac2c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 232
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011803c5cb -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3985
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011804218d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1226
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011774d7b1 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117c57dc5 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011774e2c3 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011774dcd2 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 296
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011774e0f0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 818
    19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011774d985 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117751f76 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
    21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117b6e175 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 852
    22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117c76522 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117751c91 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 153
    24  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117c76425 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    25  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117751aff -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 381
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175a56b8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 657
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175a4277 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 253
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001175a53e2 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001180406d5 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 512
    30  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117b94ec0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    31  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000115559d2e -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 419
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011557fdc1 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000115564757 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011557fa52 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111255e8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111258da2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    37  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001155a56e9 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001155a53d7 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001155a58e6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fee0eb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fee0ddc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fee05b4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fedb1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fedaac4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    45  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001158abc1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    46  UIKitCore                           0x0000000118043f80 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    47  SaralAccountsMobile                 0x000000010d6600e0 main + 112
    48  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001112e11fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```